# Gram-Schimidt process and invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the Gram-Schmidt process leaves an orthonormal set of vectors "invariant."

There is a theorem in the book such that Theorem 6.5. Let V be a nonzero finite-dimensional inner product space.
Then V has an orthonormal basis β. Furthermore, if β = {v1, v2, . . . , vn} and
x ∈ V, then
$$x =\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,vi \rangle vi$$

I just wonder if we could use that theorem to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just follow the Gram-Schmidt procedure and see what happens?  If $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is an orthonormal basis define a new set of vectors $u_1,\ldots, u_n$ obtained by performing Gram-Schmidt on your original set of vectors.  Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
u_1 & = & \frac{v_1}{||v_1||} \;\; =\;\; v_1 \\
u_2 & = & \frac{v_2 - \langle v_2, u_1\rangle u_1}{||v_2 - \langle v_2, u_1\rangle u_1||} \\
& = & \frac{v_2}{||v_2||} \;\; =\;\; v_2 \\
u_3 & = & \frac{v_3 - \langle v_3,u_1\rangle u_1- \langle v_3, u_2\rangle u_2}{||v_3 - \langle v_3,u_1\rangle u_1- \langle v_3, u_2\rangle u_2||}  \\
& = & \ldots
\end{eqnarray*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't think the expression $v_{2} - \langle v_{2},v_{1}\rangle$ makes sense. The first term is a vector while the second is a scalar.

Comment: @user1337 you’re absolutely right.  Just edited it.